# Pretty URLs for named anchors on WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a WordPress site in which the services page is one long page with anchors for each section.

www.mysite.com/services/#human-resources  jumps to the Human Resources section as expected.

Is there any way in the .htaccess file to make a url such as www.mysite.com/services/human-resources/ jump directly to the anchor?

I've tried several different rewrite rules, the closest I've gotten is:

```
RewriteRule services/human-resources services/#human-resources [NE,L,R=301]
```

But this shows the # in the url which defeats the purpose.  Removing the `R=301` just causes it to do nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a similar site and this is how I solved that issue.

First add this action to functions.php, witch redirects the user to the proper anchor on the page.

```
function url_handler(){
  $path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1); //get the path minus the '/'
  if( is_page() || is_404() ){ // do you own conditional tags
    wp_redirect( home_url("#" . $path) ); //redirect to the #anchor
    exit();
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'url_handler' );
```

Next you need to make a javascirpt handler witch gets the url of the page (the url with the anchor) and make the proper event to scroll to that section. Something like this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace('#','');
hash = hash.replace('/','');
/* do stuff here */
```

Hope this helps